# Advice needed for a switch controlling 3 switch states at once?

Tags: switches

[image]

Above are three switches for an electronic system to operate. 
SSR is a sold state relay, and L indicates the hot line for 230VAC which is powering a circuit. Switch 1 is connected to a wire in the circuit.

I need a single-throw switch when ON: switch 1 and switch 2 will be ON and switch 3 will be OFF.
And similarly when OFF: switch 1 and switch 2 will be OFF and switch 3 will be ON.

Is there any type of switch where I can achieve this goal?

edit: States of switches will change as: ON ON OFF ----> OFF OFF ON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagram isn't all that clear and you may be able to use a DPDT switch but, just in case, you can get 3PDT (Triple pole, double throw) switches like this: -

[image]

It has 3 sets of change over contacts and should suit what you want. The keyword is "3PDT". Another view is this: -

[image]

It's the one on the right. And below looks like one you can buy: -

[image]

---

Maybe you actually want this: -

[image]

Comment: Yes when the SSR is disconnected wire 1 should also be disconnected and only wire 3 should be active. and the other way around

Comment: can that handle 230VAC?

Comment: but your figures looks like they are "all on" or "all off" isnt it?

Comment: Well, I've only really informed you what to search for but there are thousands of switches of DPDT nature that easily handle 230VAC.

Comment: "all on" or "all off" - I don't know what you mean - one pole can connect to two "outlets" and there are several poles that are activated simultaneously. If this means "all on" or "all off" then yes they are.

Comment: Regarding your illustration: I think you mean to do this: When the main switch is ON: 1-2 connected(ON) 4-5 connected(ON) 8-9 connected(OFF) ...

When the main switch is OFF: 2-3 connected(OFF) 5-6 connected(OFF) 7-8 connected(ON) Did I understand  you?

Comment: With the toggle/lever in one direction, 1/2, 4/5 and 7/8 are shorted. In the other direction 2/3, 5/6 and 8/9 are shorted. You get three sets of "normally open" and "normally closed" contacts.

Comment: I see I can use it for my application as long as I find which can handle 230V 2A